# Highcharts - Drag ColumRange

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hello for my work I need to drag columnrange on highcharts.
I will explain with a schema and give you an example.

For the moment I have chart with some columnranges (duration of one task as a function of the time)

[My Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/fh9k0k2g/2/) on this link you can update directly if you want

---

Task  |----------------|

2016      2017        2018       2019      2020      2021       2022

---

And I need something like this (the arrow is normaly not visible) :

Task--------->|-----------------|

2016   2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022

---

I need to drag the entire columnrange on the xAxis or yAxis if you have inverted.

Thank you very much for your help :)

---

Here my code if you don't want open jsfiddle.net :

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Roadmap'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3', 'Task4', 'Task5', 'Task6', 'Task7', 'Task8', 'Task9', 'Task10', 'Task11', 'Task12']
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        minTickInterval: 365 * 24 * 36e5,
        labels: {
            align: 'left'
        }
    },



    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
        }
    },


    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b> ';
}
},

    series: [{
        name: 'Dates ',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2015,1,1), Date.UTC(2015,3,2)],
            [Date.UTC(2014,4,8), Date.UTC(2015,7,8)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,1,1), Date.UTC(2015,3,2)],
            [Date.UTC(2018,4,8), Date.UTC(2019,7,8)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,4,8), Date.UTC(2015,7,8)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,1,1), Date.UTC(2015,3,2)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,4,8), Date.UTC(2017,7,8)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,4,8), Date.UTC(2015,7,8)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,1,1), Date.UTC(2015,3,2)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,1,1), Date.UTC(2015,3,2)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,4,8), Date.UTC(2015,7,8)],
            [Date.UTC(2015,1,1), Date.UTC(2015,3,2)],
        ],
        type: 'columnrange',
        draggableY: true,
    }],




});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a plug-in on the Highcharts website that may be helpful for you: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable%20Points.

The example shows line and bubble charts, but I don't see why it couldn't be applied to column and bar charts with some small effort.

Comment: Thank you but I found this plug-in but I don't know how apply this to columnrange because I need to move the whole bar (x1 AND x2) or (y1 AND y2 if you inverted)

Answer (score 0):

In case of your chart you can use draggable-points plugin available on the Highcharts website:
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable%20Points

You can change this plugin a little bit if you want to be able to apply it on columnrange/arearange.

I have provided small changes to this plugin, here you can see an example how it can work with columnrange series:
http://jsfiddle.net/249e3gk6/10/

The whole code of this chart is here:

```
  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange'
    },

    series: [{
      data: [
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 5]
      ],
      cursor: 'move',
      draggableY: true,
      draggableX: true
    }]

  });

});
```

It will work fine when your chart is not inverted. If you want to have inverted functonality for this plugin you can ask for it on github of this plugin: 
https://github.com/highcharts/draggable-points/issues

Kind regards.